Is this a path issue because none of my ruby programs work?
My issue was I had rbenv and rvm installed. So I just used one, removed the other. Now my error reads what it says below and none of my ruby programs run.
-bash: /Users/.../.rbenv/shims/ruby: No such file or directory

"I just used one, removed the other" – which one did you remove and which is the one you're using? Also: how did you remove it? (in particular in regard to .bashrc / .bash_profile)

If you're unsure, remove both and start from scratch. Safest way to make sure you have a clean installation.

I removed rbenv using brew uninstall rbenv

Check your startup shell scripts to see if they still contain references to rbenv.

If you haven't already, try opening a new terminal window and run the command again (sometimes settings linger in the current terminal even after you remove the actual utilities)

If you're on a Mac, the default shell is now Zsh and treats each new Terminal window as a login shell. Adjust your shell initialization accordingly.
